# Dynamics - Normal Form

Tags: nonlinear-dynamics

Im working through the problems of Strogtz`s Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos. On problem 4.3.5, it does not ask, but is it possible to find a normal form for it? The equation is the following:

$$
\dot{\theta} = \mu+\cos(\theta)-\cos(2\theta)$$
which for the fix point $\theta^*=\pi$, $\mu_c = 2$ a bifurcation occurs.
My attempt to finding the normal form (i ploted and its seems to be a saddle node.
$$
\left.\dot{\theta}\right|_{\theta=\pi}\cong\mu+(-1+\frac{1}{2}(\theta-\pi)^2    )-(1-(\theta-\pi)^2)\\
= \mu -1 + \frac{1}{2}(\theta+\pi)^2-1 + (\theta-\pi)^2\\
\dot{\phi}= \mu + \frac{3}{2}\phi^2
$$
which is not quite the normal form $\dot{x}=r+x^2$

Comment: You can rewrite $\dot{\phi}=\mu+\frac{3}{2}\phi^2$ as $\dot{\psi}=\tilde{\mu}+\psi^2,$ where $\psi:=\frac{3}{2}\phi$ and $\tilde{\mu}:=\frac{3}{2}\mu.$